# Could not find 'railties' (>= 0.a) among 14 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems, gemspecs

When running: $rails new app I get an error!
(Recently updated ruby.)

`macOS Mojave 10.14.6`

`rails -v = ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-darwin18]`

### When running: `$rails new app`

```
/Users/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:319:in to_specs': Could not find 'railties' (>= 0.a) among 14 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
```

Checked in '`GEM_PATH=/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3:/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@global`', execute `gem env` for more information

```
from/Users/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:328:in to_spec'
    from/Users/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:65:in `gem'

from/Users/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
```

any Rails related code is not WORKING.

Comment: Exactly what `$rails new app` or `rails new app`? if `$rails new app` then it will through error

Comment: LOL, I do know how to use the command line.... the problem is showing when I run rails new app.

Comment: If you've just installed a new version of ruby, you may need to install rails:  `gem install rails`

Comment: What Yule said. Running `gem which rails` should tell you if you have rails installed.